# Converting a BufferedImage to HBITMAP

Tags: java, windows, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

I need to convert a Java BufferedImage into an HBITMAP.

So far I have allocated the memory needed for this operation, but I do not know what API functions I have to use to convert my BufferedImage into an hBitmap.

```
int width  = myImage.getWidth();
int height = myImage.getHeight();


Pointer myImageHdc = gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(Pointer.NULL);
Pointer myImageBitmap = gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(myImageHdc, width, height);

gdi32.SelectObject(myImageHdc, myImageBitmap);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're not likely to be able to simply copy a BufferedImage internal representation to an HBITMAP's internal representation; at best you might be able to get a block of pixels as integer values from one and pass it to the other.  See BufferedImage.getRaster().getPixels() for one method of extraction.